Azure retrieve files from cold storage to display in UI
I have files for 15 years worth that we show in UI.  For cost saving, i want to move all files except last few years to a cold storage.  I should still be able to retrieve these files from cold storage on a need basis, with some 24 hours delay.  Like how most banks works.  If you request for an old statement, online system notifies us whenever it is ready.
Like to gather some ideas from people who have implemented this.  We use Azure and .Net.

Cold storage is rather lose term here.  If those files are on some network storage device (say a san), then you can always use code behind to read such files if the web server has some kind of connection to where such files are stored.  For any customer files then for reasons of security I never let web based URL'S map to such files anyway.  While the web server is limited to valid URL'S,  code behind can read and fetch a file from any location on the network that the server can reach or talk to. So code behind doesn't need valid URL'S and is pure windows code

I would look at this. It looks like the Archive tier might be ok for you, 15 hours is how long it takes the archive to rehydrate, which is less than 24. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview


Azure retrieves files from cold storage to display in the UI.

You can follow this MS-Document.
To store files for cost savings, consider using the Azure Blob Storage Archive tier.
The Archive tier supports several hours of retrieval latency and is designed for data that is rarely recovered. In comparison to the Hot and Cool tiers, it offers cheaper storage; however, retrieval costs are higher, and retrieval times are longer.
Use the below code to move your old files to the Archive tier using the Azure Blob Storage SDK for .NET.
Set an access tier using code:
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;


// Retrieve the connection string for the storage account
string connectionString = "zzzzz";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("<Your-file-name>");
blobClient.SetAccessTier(AccessTier.Archive);

Output:

To retrieve files from the archive, you need to rehydrate them to the Hot or Cool tier using the same method.
Code:
var properties = blobClient.GetProperties();
if (properties.Value.AccessTier == AccessTier.Archive)
{
    blobClient.SetAccessTier(AccessTier.Cool);
    Console.WriteLine("The file will be available in Cool tier in 15 hours.");
}

You can retrieve files from the archive tier with a delay of up to 15 hours.
